# Vue Suspense in Ionic view

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, vuejs3, ionic5, vue-suspense

I have this view:

```html
<template>
  <ion-page>
    <ion-router-outlet></ion-router-outlet>
    <suspense>
      <template #default>
        {{ pages }}
      </template>
      <template #fallback>
        <div>Loading...</div>
      </template> 
    </suspense>
  </ion-page>
</template>
```

```js
...
async setup() {
    const storageRef = storage.ref();
    const bookRef = storageRef.child("content/books/bk0000001");
    const pages = await bookRef.listAll();
    console.log({ pages }); // is logged correctly

    return { pages }
}
```

Although it seems to load the content fine but the template is not rendered, the page remains empty neither the `default` not the `fallback` content is displayed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: do you render the `pages` result in place of `Show main content`?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Yes, correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a component's `setup()` is `async`, the component has to be within a `<suspense>` *in the parent* of the component (not in the component itself).

You should move the `{{ pages }}` markup and the data fetching from the `async setup()` into its own component:

```html
<!-- AsyncPages.vue -->
<template>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="page in pages" :key="page.id">{{ page.title }}</li>
  </ul>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  async setup() {
    const resp = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
    const pages = await resp.json()
    return { pages }
  }
})
</script>
```

And update the parent to use the new component in a `<suspense>`:

```html
<!-- Parent.vue -->
<template>
  <ion-page>
    <ion-router-outlet></ion-router-outlet>
    <suspense>
      <template #default>
        <AsyncPages />
      </template>
      <template #fallback>
        <div>Loading...</div>
      </template>
    </suspense>
  </ion-page>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
import AsyncPages from '@/components/AsyncPages.vue'

export default defineComponent({
  components: {
    AsyncPages
  }
})
</script>
```

[demo 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-async-setup-bhqwdk?file=src%2Fviews%2FHome.vue)

Alternatively, you could rewrite the above into a non-async `setup()`, using an `onMounted` async hook instead:

```html
<!-- Parent.vue -->
<template>
  <ion-page>
    <ion-router-outlet></ion-router-outlet>
    <ul v-if="pages">
      <li v-for="page in pages" :key="page.id">{{ page.title }}</li>
    </ul>
    <div v-else>Loading...</div>
  </ion-page>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent, onMounted, ref } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const pages = ref(null)

    onMounted(async () => {
      const resp = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      pages.value = await resp.json()
    })

    return { pages }
  }
})
</script>
```

[demo 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-loading-async-data?file=src/views/Home.vue)